# Spring Integration preventDuplicates(false) not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Given the code below, I would expect `preventDuplicates(false)` to allow files with the same name  and size and last modification to be processed. However, the code still acts as it this flag is `true` in that only a file with a new name is accepted.

The API says `Configure an AcceptOnceFileListFilter if preventDuplicates == true, otherwise - AcceptAllFileListFilter.`

Which I assume to mean that `AcceptAllFileListFilter` is being used automatically, however when setting a break-point on this filter, it is never hit.

The `patternFilter` is also not working. `*.csv` is also being processed.

Removing either/or `preventDuplicates()` or `patternFilter()` doesn't make any difference (assuming that a Filter Chain was causing the problem).

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class ApplicationTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
                        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationTest.class)
                                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                                .run(args);
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow readBackUpFlow() {
                return IntegrationFlows
                        .from(
                                Files
                                        .inboundAdapter(new File("d:/temp/in"))
                                        .patternFilter("*.txt")
                                        .preventDuplicates(false)
                                        .get(),
                                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000))
                        )

                        .log("File", m -> m)
                        .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                        .log("Content", m -> m)
                        .handle((p, h) ->  h.get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class))
                        .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File("d:/temp/done")).deleteSourceFiles(true))
                        .get();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `get()` on that `Files.inboundAdapter()`. It does some extra work in the `getComponentsToRegister()` which is called by the framework at specific phase. So, that's how your filters are not applied to the target channel adapter.